# Authorization controller MVC not with role or user but with an other parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, authorize-attribute

i wouuld like to add a customAuthorization in my controller but not by checking the role or the user.

Sommething like that `CustomModuleAuthorize("Module1")]`

In the CustomModuleAuthorize i want to redirect in an error view.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I fine a solution by creating a customModuleAttribute.
I ovveride the AuthorizeCore and HandleUnauthorizedRequest to catch the error and redirect to a view.

Here is the code

```
   public class CustomModuleAuthorization : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string NomModule { get; set; }
        private string _reason = "";

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {

            //return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            string json;
            ModulesModel module = null;

            try
            {
                //Appel de l'API pour vérification que le user à acces au module renseigné
                var windowsIdentity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity as System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;

                if (windowsIdentity == null)
                {
                    _reason = "Identity not a valid windows identity. ";
                    return false;
                }

                using (windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
                {
                    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
                    {
                        string fullUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlApiSuma"].ToString();

                        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
                        client.Headers.Add("SessionID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                        json = client.DownloadString(fullUri);
                        module = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModulesModel>(json);

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _reason = e.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Error",
                        action = "UnAuthorizedAccess",
                        module= NomModule,
                        message = _reason
                    })
                );


        }

    }
```